# CSH: Using -d as argument

Tags: arguments, csh

I know that -d can be used to test for a directory. If ( $argv[1] == "-d" ) does not work because of that. However, I need to be able to pass -d as an argument to my script. How can I disable the special property of -d so I can pass it as an argument?

Example:
Using ./script -d to launch my script with the -d argument prints a "If: missing file name" error. Using -h for example works just fine.

Obligatory CShell is harmful, but I have to use it.

Comment: please update your question with a minimal working (code) example of your problem. `-d` has no magic power except in some code like `if ( -d $p ) then ....` See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html to brush up on your csh understanding. Or if you really will be using csh until you change jobs, get http://www.amazon.com/The-Unix-Shell-Field-Guide/dp/013937468X . An excellent job of tech writing for an less than perfect technical product ;-/ Good luck.

Comment: [Also posted on unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238361/csh-using-d-as-an-argument-and-not-test)

Comment: Don't cross posting and check out [my answer in U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238385/38906).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding a dummy character before the statement. So If ( X$argv[1] == "X-d" ).

Comment: accept your answer after 48 hrs to gain reputation points. Good show for solving your own problem. In future, small samples will enable readers to help  you quickly. Sample input, required output, code, error messages, and comments on your requirements do wonders for peoples ability to help you. Good luck.